# Laravel 8 make 2 relationship between the same model

Tags: orm, foreign-keys, laravel-8

So, this is my relationship method on file model:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        User::class,
        'user_id',
        'id'
    );
}

public function modify()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        User::class,
        'update_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

[This is my model table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M7hE.png)

This is my model migration code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('update_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreignId('division_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->text('details');
        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is my view code:

```
@foreach ($files as $key=>$file)    
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $files->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $file->title }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('Files.index', ['division'=>$file->division->slug, 'byUser'=>$byUser]) }}">{{ $file->division->name }}</a></td>
            <td>
                @if (auth()->user()->id == 1)
                    <a href="{{ route('Files.index', ['division'=>$division, 'byUser'=>$file->user->username]) }}">{{ $file->user->name }}</a>
                @else
                    {{ $file->user->name }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>{{ $file->created_at }}</td>
            <td>
                {{-- @foreach ($file->modify as $update) --}}
                    {{ dd($file->modify->name) }}
```

[This is my page view look like after executing code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUIXt.png)

after change this line:

`{{ dd($file->modify->name) }}`

to:

`{{ ($file->modify->name) }}`

i got the following error:

**ErrorException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem like the first `$file` in you array has the `modify` relationship set but there's a subsequent `$file` that's missing it. Either do a null check or make sure that the relationship is always set.

Comment: thanks, for advice, now i can assign NULL, in the view, i check wether the relation is True, using @if ($file->modify)